# Typescript return type specific components or null

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So, I have one function that returns an array.map, and this map should return null or one of two elements (has to be them because they are part of a parent component outside the map) or recursively call the function depending on a specific rule.

```
<Menu inlineCollapsed={isCollapsed} mode="inline">
        {mapRoutes(routes)}
</Menu>

const mapRoutes = (targetRoutes: IRoute[]): (ReactNode | null)[] | null => {
    if (targetRoutes && targetRoutes.length > 0) {
      return targetRoutes.map((route: IRoute) => {
        if (!route.name) return null;
        if (route.routes) {
          return (
            <SubMenu key={route.key} icon={route.icon} title={route.name}>
              {mapRoutes(route.routes)}
            </SubMenu>
          );
        }
        return (
          <Item key={route.key} icon={route.icon}>
            <Link to={route.path}>{route.name}</Link>
          </Item>
        );
      });
    }
    return null;
  };
```

I want to know if the return type of this function could be something like:

```
(): SubItem[] | Item[] | null
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Sure, that's a valid type after all

Comment: But when I try like that it returns this error:

'SubMenu' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof SubMenu'?ts(2749)

when using typeof SubMenu:

Type '(Element | null)[]' is not assignable to type '(typeof SubMenu | null)[]'.
  Type 'Element | null' is not assignable to type 'typeof SubMenu | null'.
    Type 'Element' is missing the following properties from type 'typeof SubMenu': prototype, contextType, isSubMenuts(2322)

Comment: Also, if I pass ReactElement<typeof SubMenu> it does work. But it do not give errors when returning other element besides it.